# In Pandas i could not filter the dataframe with where function , returning still complete data set

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv')

>>> len(df)

126314

>>> len(df.where(df["fran_id"]=="Lakers"))

126314

>>> len(df[df["fran_id"]=="Lakers"])

6024
>>>
```

Can someone help what is wrong in where function I used ?

Comment: what's wrong with it??  you need to use the last option to get the subset of df!!!

Comment: since where method replaces data with NaN's where condition aren't met so that's why you are getting the same length as your actual dataframe but in the second one you are filtering your condition so that's why you are getting length of dataframe where your condition met

Comment: @AnuragDabas thanks got it, so where function is not used for filtering the data in pandas but to replace the unmatching records with some value

Comment: you can also use `where()` method but with `dropna()` method for filtering purpose check: `len(df.where(df["fran_id"]=="Lakers").dropna())`

Comment: Yes but dropna() remove all rows even if any other columns is having null values.

Comment: then use `df[df["fran_id"]=="Lakers"]` or `df.query("fran_id=='Lakers'")` for filtering purpose

Comment: thanks @AnuragDabas , this perfectly solves the problem !!